# Need a one liner to extract members of a python list to varaibles (applies to many languages)

Tags: python, list, variables, extract, one-liner

This is related to processing commandline-like arguments.

Given a list of strings, I want to extract those strings into variables with the added feature that the last variable list receives any remaining list elements as a slice of the list, the remainders of those that were not extracted, like this:

```
    command, target, operation, parameters = 
    some_function(["grant", "woody", "rights", "read", "write", "delete"])
```

after `some_function` is executed, the variables should have these values:

```
command = "grant"
target = "woody"
operation = "rights"
parameters = ["read", "write", "delete"]
```

I will write my own function if I have to but I was wondering if python has a tight way of doing that.

Comment: Look into unpacking

Comment: use `command, target, operation, *parameters = ["grant", "woody", "rights", "read", "write", "delete"]`

Comment: Now THAT'S what I'm talking about! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
command, target, operation, *parameters = ["grant", "woody", "rights", "read", "write", "delete"]

print(command)
print(target)
print(operation)
print(parameters)
```

**Output**

```
grant
woody
rights
['read', 'write', 'delete']
```